# SharePoint Online Json formatting. Highlight 1 column if several others are filled in

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to include a column to basically serve as a checklist for several other columns.

The column 'Can we launch' is supposed to fill as green when all referred to columns are filled in.

If one of the to check columns is empty it should fill in as red.

I am struggling stringing this all together, and hoping an expert can set me in the right direction!

Below I am adding a screenshot of an example/
For the bottom line the Can we launch? column should fill green, all others it should fill in as red.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON column formatting on "Can we launch?" column for your requirements.

Use JSON like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "white",
        "background-color": "=if([$MAReceived] && [$SAPIDs] && [$PacksizesForCTG] && [$PacksizesForLA] && [$Artworks] && [$BUForecastSal], 'green', 'red')"
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of all your columns in JSON like `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. You can find the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

You can add more columns in `if` expression or customize the `style` as per your requirements. Follow documentation for more information, syntax and styling options available using JSON formatting: [JSON formatting syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)